# Usar metodo de una clase interna en el main

Tags: java

Tengo una clase alumo en la cual tengo estas tres variables internas:

```
private String nombre;//Nombre de la persona
private int edad;//Edad de la persona entre 18 y 99
private Nota notas[];//Array de objeto de notas
```

Tengo su constructor vacio, tambien hecho un constructor con todas las variables, getter y setters.

Esta es la clase interna que he creado:

```
private class Nota {

    String asignatura;//Solo puede ser bbdd y programacion

    byte calificacion;//calificacion valor entre 0 - 10

    Nota(String a, byte c) {
        asignatura = a;
        calificacion = c;
    }

    Nota() {

    }

    public String getAsignatura() {
        return asignatura;
    }

    public byte getCalificacion() {
        return calificacion;
    }

}
```

En el main estoy pidiendo por teclado los valores.

```
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    Alumno pepe=new Alumno();
    System.out.println("Dime el nombre");
    String nombre=sc.nextLine();
    byte edad=2;
    do{


    System.out.println("Dime la edad debe de ser de 0 hasta 99");
    edad =Byte.parseByte(sc.nextLine());
    pepe.ajustarEdad(edad);
    }while(pepe.ajustarEdad(edad)!=true);
     pepe.setEdad(edad);
     String nombreAsignauta="";
      byte nota=0;
      byte cantidad=0;
      System.out.println("Dime cuantas asignaturas tienes");
      cantidad=Byte.parseByte(sc.nextLine());


     }
```

Pero a la hora de intentar acceder al array interno de notas no puedo usar los getter y setter que tiene la calse interna de alumno.

Simplemente quiero perdir en el main por teclado cuantas asignaturas tienes, y cuales son.
Luego le pasaria este metodo que tengo en la clase alumno:

```
public void ajustarNotas() {
    byte cantidad = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.notas.length; i++) {
        if (notas[i].asignatura.equalsIgnoreCase("programacion")
            || notas[i].asignatura.equalsIgnoreCase("bbdd")) {
            cantidad++;
        }
    }
    Nota[] notaAjustada = new Nota[cantidad];
    byte contador = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {
        if (notas[i].asignatura.equalsIgnoreCase("programacion")
            || notas[i].asignatura.equalsIgnoreCase("bbdd")) {
            notaAjustada[contador] = notas[i];
            contador++;
        }
    }
    this.notas = notaAjustada;
      }
```

Como puedo acceder a la clase interna o al menos crear un array de tipo Notas estableciendo la cantidad del array y luego las asignatura(querria establacer las asignaturas como la calificacion en un bucle)?

Comment: Creo que tu problema reside en que tu clase Nota es private y debería ser public para que puedas acceder a ella.

Comment: Al final lo he conseguido.
Gracias por vuestras ayudas bros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debería declarar la clase "interna" como publica, y agregar los métodos get y set para cada campo o sea:

```
public class Nota {

private String asignatura;//Solo puede ser bbdd y programacion

private byte calificacion;//calificacion valor entre 0 - 10

public Nota(String a, byte c) {
    asignatura = a;
    calificacion = c;
}


public Nota() {

}


 public String getAsignatura() {
return asignatura;
} 

public void setAsignatura(String asignatura) {
this. asignatura = asignatura;
}

public String getCalificacion() {
return calificacion;
}


 public void setCalificacion(byte calificacion) {
 this.calificacion = calificacion;
  }



 }
```

Comment: Lo he hecho publico pero sigo sin poder acceder a setAsignatura

Comment: Probaste  inicializar el array de notas en la clase Alumno? private Nota notas[] = new notas[20];